# How to call function from a view when using nested controllers - AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In `view.html` `tableUserCtrl` is parent controller and `ModalDemoCtrl` is child controller. Now I need to call `userAddT` function written in `tableUserCtrl` from `view.html` when user submit the form. When I keep that function in `ModalDemoCtrl` in `ui-bootstrape.js` its working but in `ModalDemoCtrl` I can't use `$scope.data.push` and I need to add dynamic raw to my `datatable` so my question is how to call parent controller function from child controller from view when both controller are written in different js files?

I have used `$parent.userAddT` in `view.html` but it's not working. Can anyone give me the solution? I am new to AngularJS.

Here is my code:

table.js

```
//user
.controller('tableUserCtrl', function($scope, $filter, $sce, ngTableParams, tableService) {
    //var data = tableService.data;

    var selfUser = this; 
    $scope.data = [];
    //selfUser.obj = null;
    var promise = tableService.getUserData();

    promise.then(
        function(payload) { 

            $scope.data = payload.data;

            $scope.tableEdit = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,            // show first page
                count: 10,           // count per page  
                sorting: {
                    name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
                }                   
            }, {
                total: $scope.data.length, // length of data
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    //$defer.resolve(selfUser.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

                    //sorting                       
                    var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.data, params.orderBy()) : $scope.data;

                    //filtering
                    orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(orderedData, params.filter()) : orderedData;

                    //orderedData = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

                    //params.total(orderedData.length);
                    //$defer.resolve(orderedData);
                    $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));

                }
            });                 
        },
        function(errorPayload) {
          $log.error('failure loading movie', errorPayload);
        }); 

    //to update data    
    $scope.updateUser = function(w) {
        tableService.updateUserData(w);
    }       

    $scope.removeUser = function(id, w) {
        tableService.removeUserData(id)
        //alert(JSON.stringify($scope.data))
        $scope.data.splice($scope.data.indexOf(w), 1);
        $scope.tableEdit.reload();
        //alert(JSON.stringify($scope.data))
    }

    $scope.addUserT = function(w) {
        alert("hey")
        tableService.addUserData(w)
        //$scop.data.push()
        //$scope.tableEdit.reload()
    }       
})
```

ui-bootstrape.js

```
.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

    $scope.modalContent = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sodales orci ante, sed ornare eros vestibulum ut. Ut accumsan vitae eros sit amet tristique. Nullam scelerisque nunc enim, non dignissim nibh faucibus ullamcorper. Fusce pulvinar libero vel ligula iaculis ullamcorper. Integer dapibus, mi ac tempor varius, purus nibh mattis erat, vitae porta nunc nisi non tellus. Vivamus mollis ante non massa egestas fringilla. Vestibulum egestas consectetur nunc at ultricies. Morbi quis consectetur nunc.';

    //Create Modal
    function modalInstances(animation, size, backdrop, keyboard, htmlurl) {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: animation,
            templateUrl: htmlurl + '.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
            backdrop: backdrop,
            keyboard: keyboard,
            resolve: {
                content: function () {
                    return $scope.modalContent;
                }
            }            
        });
    }

    //Prevent Outside Click
    $scope.openStatic = function (htmlurl) {
        modalInstances(true, '', 'static', true , htmlurl)
    };

    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, content, tableService) {

          $scope.modalContent = content;

          $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
          };

          $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
          };

          $scope.addUser = function(w) {
            tableService.addUserData(w)
          }

    })

})
```

view.html

```
<section id="content">
    <div class="container" data-ng-controller="tableUserCtrl">

        <div class="p-t-0" data-ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">                
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="adduser.html">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <!--<h4 class="modal-title">Add User</h4>-->
                </div>
                <form role="form" ng-submit="insertInfo(userInfo);" name="userForm" novalidate>
                    ...
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="ok(); $parent.addUserT(user);" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </script>
            <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="openStatic('adduser')">Add User</button><br/><br/>
        </div>  

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h2>Users <small></small></h2>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table ng-table="tableEdit" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle" show-filter="true">
                        <tr ng-repeat="w in $data"  ng-class="{ 'active': w.$edit }">
                            <td data-title="'ID'" filter="{ 'role_no': 'text' }" sortable="'role_no'">
                                <span ng-if="!w.$edit">{{ w.role_no }}</span>
                                <div ng-if="w.$edit"><input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="w.role_no" /></div>
                            </td>
                            ...
                            <td data-title="'Actions'">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="!w.$edit" ng-click="w.$edit = true"><i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="!w.$edit" ng-click="removeUser(w.user_id, w)"><i class="zmdi zmdi-close"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-if="w.$edit" ng-click="w.$edit = false; updateUser(w)"><i class="zmdi zmdi-check"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to call your function from your child scope.
Instead add a function to resolve the promise of the dialog :

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open(
    ...
);
modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
    tableService.addUserData(result)
});
```

You need to pass your user as parameter of the close function :

```
$modalInstance.close($scope.user);
```

**Updated**

In your controller `tableUserCtrl` add a method to open the dialog and track result:

```
$scope.openDialog = function () {
    // TODO: replace option dialog with your options:
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: viewsPath + 'addUserView.html',
        controller: 'addUserCtrl',
        size: 'md',
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: true,
        resolve: {
            content: function () {
                return $scope.modalContent;
            }
        }            
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
        // Add user in you database
        tableService.addUserData(result);
        // Add user in your view
        $scope.data.push(result);
    };
});
```

Create a separated view for your dialog (adduserView.html):

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Add User</h4>
</div>
    <form role="form" ng-submit="insertInfo(userInfo);" name="userForm" novalidate>
    ...
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="ok();" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Create a controller addUserCtrl:

```
.controller('addUserCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, content) {

      $scope.modalContent = content;

      $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close($scope.user);
      };

      $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };
});
```

Remove the controllers ModalDemoCtrl and ModalInstanceCtrl

Comment: Okay! I got it but that's just alternate way of calling function from `ModalDemoCtrl`.

Comment: My issue is that I have to use `$scope.data.push` to add raw to my datatable. So how can I use it in `ModalDemoCtrl`?

Comment: add a function openModal in your `tableUserCtrl` to call `var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({..});` and  `modalInstance.result.then(...) ` add your data.push in the promise result and remove the unused `ModalDemoCtrl`. Keep only `ModalInstanceCtrl`

Comment: I am not getting what you trying to say. I don't have much knowledge about AngularJS. Will you please add some code where I need to change?